# jQuery custom functions

Tags: jquery

Why the value of `oldHeight` is not overridden ? It still has `oldHeight` to `80` not what i have passed as argument. Even if i pass argument `newHeight`, it will also not override it. But according to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring), it will automatically updated. Here's the code:

```
( function($) {
$.fn.bad = function(callback) {
    var options;
    var settings = $.extend({
        "oldHeight":"80",
        "newHeight":"200"
    }, options);
    return this.each( function() {
        var that$ = $(this);
        that$.bind("mouseenter", function() {
            $(this).animate({ "height" : settings.newHeight+"px" });
        }).bind("mouseleave", function() {
            $(this).animate({ "height" : settings.oldHeight+"px" });
        });
    });
}
})(jQuery);
$(".box").bad({"oldHeight":"400"});
```

And this ===> [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/cGSNn/)

Comment: It is overriding, isn't it? the box is getting bigger on the fiddle

Comment: hey, i have assigned `400` when the mouseleave but it is limited to default option.

Comment: oops, my bad .. misread the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized "options" with null with `var options;` and extended your settings with an empty value.

```js
( function($) {
    $.fn.bad = function(options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                "oldHeight":"80",
                "newHeight":"200"
            }, options);

    ...
```

this works.

Comment: Thanks, i just started. I didn't noticed that i have already `callback` as parameter. Just was following the documentation and got confused. I didn't even noticed that i have to assign that `callback` variable to `$.extend({})` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try ths,

```
var settings = {};
var settings = $.extend(settings, {
    "oldHeight":"80",
    "newHeight":"200"
}, options);
```

Your function needs to accept the `options` not the `callback` (if there is no callback being used).

So your code will be,

```
(function($) {
$.fn.bad = function(options) {
    var settings = {};
    var settings = $.extend(settings, {
        "oldHeight":"80",
        "newHeight":"200"
    }, options);
    ...
```

[Test](http://jsfiddle.net/cGSNn/4/)

Comment: I just named it `callback`. However, naming `options` is not mandatory. http://jsfiddle.net/cGSNn/5/

Comment: Yes, it's not mandatory, but makes more sense semantically :)

Comment: well, ok. +1 for the effort.